# An identity about antipode in a Poisson Hopf algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, hopf-algebras

Let $H$ be a Poisson Hopf algebra. Then the antipode $S : H \to H$ is a Poisson algebra antimorphism provided $H$ is commutative.

This fact is proved in Lemma 2.6 of [the paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1601.04269v1.pdf).

An identity about antipode is used:
\begin{align}
\{a_1, b_1\}S(a_2 b_2) + a_1 b_1 S(\{a_2, b_2\})=0.
\end{align}
Here $a_1 \otimes a_2 = \Delta(a)$. How to prove this identity? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a,b\in H$. Then by the first part of the proof of Lemma 2.6 of the paper, we have
\begin{align}
\epsilon(\{a,b\}) = 0.
\end{align}
By the axioms of Hopf algebras we have
\begin{align}
m\circ (1 \otimes S) \circ \Delta = \eta \circ \epsilon.
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
(m\circ (1 \otimes S) \circ \Delta)(\{a,b\}) = (\eta \circ \epsilon)(\{a,b\})=0.
\end{align}
By the axioms of Poisson Hopf algebras, we have
\begin{align}
& (m\circ (1 \otimes S))(\Delta \{a,b\}) \\
& = (m\circ (1 \otimes S))(\{\Delta(a),\Delta(b)\}) \\
& = (m\circ (1 \otimes S))(\{a_1 \otimes a_2,b_1 \otimes b_2\}) \\
& = (m\circ (1 \otimes S))(\{a_1,b_1\} \otimes a_2 b_2 + a_1 b_1 \otimes \{a_2, b_2\}) \\
& =  \{a_1,b_1\} S( a_2 b_2 ) + a_1 b_1 S(\{a_2, b_2\}).
\end{align}
Therefore
\begin{align}
\{a_1,b_1\} S( a_2 b_2 ) + a_1 b_1 S(\{a_2, b_2\}) = 0.
\end{align}

Comment: +1 for finding the answrer yourself before anybody else responds.